# Convert Song Object to bytes WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, xna

I want to save the audio data of `Song` object or an audio file as bytes and then read the bytes and save it as as another audio file in WP7 using C#.

Let me know if question is not clear enough.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to convert a song to byte array

Comment: You're still not providing enough detail. Is it the *audio data* associated with the `Song` object that you want to put into a byte array? And then, if so, for what purpose? Do you have any specific format requirements?

Comment: *Yes*, we understand that you have a `Song` object. What data *specifically* are you trying to get? **What is "the data"?** In addition, "bytes" is not specific enough either - you need to tell us what *format* you expect those bytes to be in **or** what you intend to do with the data so that we may infer the correct format. (Also you don't play a `Song` with `MediaLibrary` you play it with `MediaPlayer.Play`.)

Comment: Yes, its the audio data. What I have is Song: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song.aspx I play it with MediaLibrary of XNA. Now I want to convert that Song which contains

Comment: Yes. you are correct. it is the audio data. once the data is in bytes i will remove a part of it and convert back the audio data to wma or mp3 (any audio formart supported by WP7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now i don't see any way to do this.You can also check [this post](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/74504/453821.aspx) on msdn with the same query.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

Serialize / deserialize it manually using [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) / [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

OR

Save it as XML using [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and then get the bytes using [`Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

I'd recommend the first as `DataContractSerializer` has overhead in both performance and serialized size.